# What is the command for opening a new terminal window and executing a series of commands?

Tags: command-line, bash

#### I am on Linux Mint 19.03

First of all, I can assure you that I have read most of the possible questions you might think this question of mine is a duplicate of.

Now, I basically want to type something in my terminal window to open a new terminal window and execute the commands.

Something like this:

```
[the part I am asking of] "echo $PATH; read"
```

This code should do open a new terminal, the $PATH variable should be displayed and `read` is just for halting the terminal.

I tried `x-terminal-emulator -e` or `x-terminal-emulator -c` or `-x` but I could never achieve to do this correctly.

All answers on this SE on the similar questions are both old answers and were using `-e` or `-x` but it says that those options are deprecated.

So, what is the most proper way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is deprecated, you should use `--` instead of `-e` or `-x`.